# Run a Pig script using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-pig

I have Pig script which I need to integrate with spark framework so that If I run spark program I should able to run the Pig Script also. How to do that ?

Please help me in this matter.Thanks a lot !

Comment: why do you want run pig script using spark... convert that into spark ??

Comment: I have a pig script which analyzes a log file to find errors and warnings. I want that to be in a framework for which I chose Spark.

Comment: humm.. I don't see any methods to invoke pig scripts in spark... may be you need to write custom methods to invoke your pig scripts inside spark code.

Comment: Ok I will try in that way.Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be overthinking the integration. The normal pattern would be:

1. Do first spark job, store results
2. Do pig job on these results and store second results
3. Do second spark job on second results

This could be coordinated by a scheduler, for instance oozie or airflow.